# Program to generate a tree of permutations

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, combinatorics, complexity

There is a computation I'm doing with permutations (permutations of varying length of an entire interval [1,N] for some N) in python that I feel could be faster.

```
from itertools import chain

def permtrim(perm):
    L = len(perm)
    while L > 2 and perm[-1] == L:
        L = perm.pop() - 1
    return perm
    
def has_bruhat_descent(perm,i,j):
    if perm[i]<perm[j]:
        return False
    for p in range(i+1,j):
        if perm[i]>perm[p] and perm[p]>perm[j]:
            return False
    return True

def kdown_perms(perm,p,k):
    full_perm_list = [(tuple(perm),0,1)]
    down_perm_list = [(list(perm),1)]
    if len(perm)<k:
        return full_perm_list
    a2 = k-1
    for pp in range(1,p+1):
        down_perm_list2 = []
        for perm2, s in down_perm_list:
            L = len(perm2)
            if L<k:
                continue            
            for b in chain(range(k-1),range(k,L)):
                if perm2[b] != perm[b]:
                    continue
                if b < a2:
                    i,j,s2 = b,a2,-s                    
                else:
                    i,j,s2 = a2,b,s
                if has_bruhat_descent(perm2,i,j):
                    new_perm = [*perm2]
                    new_perm[a2],new_perm[b] = new_perm[b],new_perm[a2]
                    permtrim(new_perm)
                    down_perm_list2 += [(new_perm,s2)]
                    full_perm_list += [(tuple(new_perm),pp,s2)]
        down_perm_list = down_perm_list2
    return full_perm_list

def compute_vpathdicts(th,vmu):
    vpathdicts = [{} for index in range(len(th))]
    vpathdicts[0][tuple(vmu)] = set()
    for i in range(len(th)):
        k = i+1
        for last_perm in vpathdicts[i]:
            newperms = kdown_perms(list(last_perm),th[i],k)
            if i == len(th) - 1:
                vpathdicts[i][last_perm]=[trip for trip in newperms if trip[0] == (1,2)]
            else:
                vpathdicts[i][last_perm]=newperms
                for trip in newperms:
                    if trip[0] not in vpathdicts[i+1]:
                        vpathdicts[i+1][trip[0]] = []
    bad_perms = [set() for i in range(len(th))] + [set()]
    for i in range(len(th)-1,-1,-1):
        newdict = {}
        for key, value in vpathdicts[i].items():
            value2 = set([trip for trip in value if trip[0] not in bad_perms[i+1]])
            if len(value2) != 0:
                newdict[key] = value2
            else:
                bad_perms[i].add(key)
        vpathdicts[i] = newdict
    return vpathdicts
    
compute_vpathdicts([8, 8, 8, 8, 8],[5, 7, 8, 10, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 9, 11])
```

The last line is just an example run for anyone who wants to see the results.

I've included the `cProfile` output at the end of the question. The main consideration in the length of time it will take is a bit lengthy to explain. If you play around with this, it will seem like every permutation is a special snowflake; you'll find long ones that take no time and shorter ones that use gigabytes of memory. It's dependent on the organization of the [code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmer_code) of the permutation, how close it is to being a decreasing sequence.

The goal is to construct a tree of permutations (really tuples, first element permutation, second element 1 or -1, and third element an integer) where we start at the permutation `vmu` and we are tracing our way down to the permutation `[1,2]`. We are given a nonincreasing list of nonzero integers `th`. We loop over the length of `th`. At index `i`, we are allowed to apply a number of transpositions (exchanging two elements), from 0 up to `th[i]` many, that include the index `i`, where each transposition must decrease the number of inversions by exactly 1 (`has_bruhat_descent` checks if applying a transposition will decrease the number of inversions by exactly 1). We keep track of a sign; for each transposition exchanging `a` and `i` with `a<i` we apply a factor of -1 to the sign, and the third element is the difference in the number of inversions. `permtrim` shaves off extraneous elements of the permutation. If the permutation has length `n` and the element at index `n-1` is equal to `n`, we can trim off the `n` to make a smaller permutation that, for our purposes, represents the same thing.

I tried something in `kdown_perms` that theoretically should have better asymptotic complexity, n log(n) instead of n^2, but the overhead was not worth it since the permutations are small. It was actually much slower for large cases, including the case above. The problem really is the sheer number of calls. For example, in `compute_vpathdicts` I noticed there was a part where it was calling `permtrim` unnecessarily. I removed the extra call and it shaved off 20 seconds.

It's also generating a lot of bad paths (paths that don't end in `[1,2]`), which I'm not sure can be helped. These are pruned at the end (the `bad_perms` section).

For full disclosure as to what this is really doing, for anyone interested, it is a step in the computation of a (double) [Schubert polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schubert_polynomial), in a method suitable for multiplying them (which is what this is used for in the larger program, of which this is the slowest part).

As promised, the cProfile output.

```
         309446316 function calls in 287.645 seconds

   Ordered by: cumulative time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000  287.645  287.645 {built-in method builtins.exec}
        1    0.019    0.019  287.645  287.645 compute_vpathdicts_test.py:1(<module>)
        1    7.495    7.495  287.626  287.626 compute_vpathdicts_test.py:46(compute_vpathdicts)
    65557  201.170    0.003  274.583    0.004 compute_vpathdicts_test.py:18(kdown_perms)
187078582   54.605    0.000   54.605    0.000 compute_vpathdicts_test.py:10(has_bruhat_descent)
 43603787   13.412    0.000   16.418    0.000 compute_vpathdicts_test.py:3(permtrim)
 78390954    5.402    0.000    5.402    0.000 {built-in method builtins.len}
    61904    5.289    0.000    5.289    0.000 compute_vpathdicts_test.py:54(<listcomp>)
    65557    0.226    0.000    0.226    0.000 compute_vpathdicts_test.py:63(<listcomp>)
   114429    0.014    0.000    0.014    0.000 {method 'pop' of 'list' objects}
    65535    0.013    0.000    0.013    0.000 {method 'add' of 'set' objects}
        5    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'items' of 'dict' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 compute_vpathdicts_test.py:59(<listcomp>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 compute_vpathdicts_test.py:47(<listcomp>)
```

**Update** I found a way to avoid generating many of the bad paths. The new code stops searching as soon as a condition is hit where it's no longer possible to continue. This cut the runtime by quite a bit. Here is the new code. I picked a bigger example because for the previous one the runtime was reduced by a factor of almost 10. I wasn't sure whether to make it an answer or part of the question.

```
from itertools import chain
from functools import cache

def inv(perm):
    return inv_cache(tuple(perm))

@cache
def inv_cache(perm):
    res = 0    
    for i in range(len(perm)):
        for j in range(i+1,len(perm)):
            if perm[i]>perm[j]:
                res+=1
    return res

def permtrim(perm):
    L = len(perm)
    while L > 2 and perm[-1] == L:
        L = perm.pop() - 1
    return perm

def has_bruhat_descent(perm,i,j):
    if perm[i]<perm[j]:
        return False
    for p in range(i+1,j):
        if perm[i]>perm[p] and perm[p]>perm[j]:
            return False
    return True

def kdown_perms(perm,minp,p,k):    
    if minp>p:
        return []
    full_perm_list = [(tuple(perm),0,1)]
    down_perm_list = [(list(perm),1)]
    if len(perm)<k:
        return full_perm_list
    a2 = k-1
    for pp in range(1,p+1):
        down_perm_list2 = []
        for perm2, s in down_perm_list:
            L = len(perm2)
            if L<k:
                continue            
            for b in chain(range(k-1),range(k,L)):
                if perm2[b] != perm[b]:
                    continue
                if b < a2:
                    i,j,s2 = b,a2,-s                    
                else:
                    i,j,s2 = a2,b,s
                if has_bruhat_descent(perm2,i,j):
                    new_perm = [*perm2]
                    new_perm[a2],new_perm[b] = new_perm[b],new_perm[a2]
                    permtrim(new_perm)
                    down_perm_list2 += [(new_perm,s2)]
                    if pp>=minp:
                        full_perm_list += [(tuple(new_perm),pp,s2)]
        down_perm_list = down_perm_list2
    return full_perm_list

def compute_vpathdicts(th,vmu):
    vpathdicts = [{} for index in range(len(th))]
    vpathdicts[0][tuple(vmu)] = set()
    S = sum(th)
    for i in range(len(th)):
        k = i+1
        for last_perm in vpathdicts[i]:
            newperms = kdown_perms(list(last_perm),max(0,inv(last_perm)-S),th[i],k)
            if i == len(th) - 1:
                vpathdicts[i][last_perm]=[trip for trip in newperms if trip[0] == (1,2)]
            else:
                vpathdicts[i][last_perm]=newperms
                for trip in newperms:
                    vpathdicts[i+1][trip[0]] = []
        S -= th[i]
    bad_perms = [set() for i in range(len(th))] + [set()]
    for i in range(len(th)-1,-1,-1):
        newdict = {}
        for key, value in vpathdicts[i].items():
            value2 = set([trip for trip in value if trip[0] not in bad_perms[i+1]])
            if len(value2) != 0:
                newdict[key] = value2
            else:
                bad_perms[i].add(key)
        vpathdicts[i] = newdict
    return vpathdicts
    
compute_vpathdicts([7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 4, 3],[4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 3, 5, 1, 2, 7, 11])
```

with `cProfile`:

```
         123169517 function calls in 142.894 seconds

   Ordered by: cumulative time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000  142.894  142.894 {built-in method builtins.exec}
        1    0.062    0.062  142.894  142.894 compute_vpathdicts_test.py:1(<module>)
        1   10.437   10.437  142.832  142.832 compute_vpathdicts_test.py:61(compute_vpathdicts)
   436405   95.025    0.000  122.710    0.000 compute_vpathdicts_test.py:30(kdown_perms)
 78101122   21.357    0.000   21.357    0.000 compute_vpathdicts_test.py:22(has_bruhat_descent)
 13524062    4.507    0.000    5.533    0.000 compute_vpathdicts_test.py:16(permtrim)
   436405    0.560    0.000    4.435    0.000 compute_vpathdicts_test.py:4(inv)
   290881    3.565    0.000    3.875    0.000 compute_vpathdicts_test.py:7(inv_cache)
   436405    2.780    0.000    2.780    0.000 compute_vpathdicts_test.py:80(<listcomp>)
   436405    2.231    0.000    2.231    0.000 {built-in method builtins.max}
 28959122    2.199    0.000    2.199    0.000 {built-in method builtins.len}
   436064    0.154    0.000    0.154    0.000 {method 'add' of 'set' objects}
    87360    0.013    0.000    0.013    0.000 {method 'pop' of 'list' objects}
    25251    0.004    0.000    0.004    0.000 compute_vpathdicts_test.py:70(<listcomp>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 functools.py:651(cache)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 functools.py:518(decorating_function)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 functools.py:35(update_wrapper)
        9    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'items' of 'dict' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 functools.py:479(lru_cache)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 compute_vpathdicts_test.py:76(<listcomp>)
        7    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.getattr}
        5    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.setattr}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 compute_vpathdicts_test.py:62(<listcomp>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.sum}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.isinstance}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.callable}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'update' of 'dict' objects}
```

Comment: This question is about elapsed times. You mentioned a very nice `compute_vpathdicts` example. Please include selected [cProfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html#module-cProfile) output as part of the question, so we can see where the cycles went.

Comment: @J_H Sure. I'm actually going to change the example to a more reasonable one, that one uses so much virtual memory it's hitting the disk at 900MB/s.

Comment: @J_H Added with an example that takes longer but doesn't blow up the machine.

Comment: Given the title, I expected your code to generate permutations of a set of elements. It would be better if the title was like "Schubert double polynomial" or "an intermediate step in double Schubert polynomial computation"

Comment: @slepic It does generate the permutations only in this code. These are later used as spots to sum parts of a Schubert polynomial.

Comment: @slepic I made the title more specific that it's computing the tree, hopefully that's less misleading.

Comment: @J_H I found a massive optimization that reduced this case to 31 seconds (half the time without cProfile). Do I answer the question?

Comment: cProfile helps guide us to the places that matter, yes. Tiny style nit: you have adopted list(x) rather than x.copy(), fine. Recommend you stick with that idiom, e.g. when assigning `new_perm = [*perm2]`. Here's a bigger item, on memoizing. Some, though not the bulk, of our time is spent on bruhat, so it must be the case that `range(i+1, j)` is often a "big" range, noticeably time consuming. Yet the comparison is sooo simple, and often unchanging. I wonder, could we cache / memoize the result, while noticing when a change invalidates the cache? Or then we update a cache entry?

Comment: @J_H I think `has_bruhat_descent` takes up so much time just because it is called so often. The permutations, at least in this case, will never be over length 12, so the worst it can be is 25 comparisons. I also feel like memoizing wouldn't help, but I'm not 100% sure. I don't think it's called with the same parameters very often, though it's hard to say.

Comment: @J_H I added the optimized code with cProfile output to the question.

Comment: @J_H Attempting to memoize `has_bruhat_descent` more than doubles the runtime, so it seems that I was right.

Comment: That's cool, live and learn. Glad to see the experiment tried, even if it didn't pan out. Now we're older and wiser, and we know a bit more about the problem space.

Comment: @J_H I'm doing some debug output and discovered it's generating a thousand times more bad permutations that have to be pruned than ones that remain. I found another condition that reduces it by a third in this case. It seems like small optimizations are not the trick, it's pruning.

Comment: @J_H So there are numerous ways to do this calculation for the larger problem, and I found a way to do it in 8 seconds for this case. My advisor's C program for computing the constant coefficients (a special case) typically is 5 to 10 times faster than mine. I found a monster case with huge coefficient values I've never seen before where my optimized program runs in 51 seconds and I started my advisor's program 20 minutes ago and it's still not done. `compute_vpathdicts` takes 32 seconds in the monster case. So I'd call it a success.